# How to change icon on click?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a button on my page that looks like this: https://pierdzialka.misumi.me/d2TVS.png
Once you click it the `playPreview()` is called to play an audio file.

```
var preview = document.getElementById("BeatmapPreview");
var isPlaying = false;

function playPreview() {
 if (isPlaying) {
  preview.pause();
  classList.toggle("play");
 } else {
  preview.play();
  classList.toggle("pause");
 }
};

preview.onplaying = function() {
 isPlaying = true;
};

preview.onpause = function() {
 isPlaying = false;
};
```

I'm trying to make it change the icon class from play to pause on click too, the code for that is here:

```html
<a onclick="playPreview()" class="ui blue labeled icon button">
  <i class="play icon"></i> 
  {{ $.T "Play" }}
</a>
```

How can I achieve this?

Final thing too is for the audio actually being played, that is placed further up and is just this:

```html
<audio id="BeatmapPreview">
  <source src="https://misumi.me/preview/{{ .Beatmapset.ID }}.mp3">
</audio>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this `document.getElementById('yourIconElementId').classList.toggle("play");`

Add your Icon Element selector before `classList`

Comment: When you press play, it switches the icon to pause but once you press it after it remains on pause. Any reason?

Comment: When I inspect element and press it, after like 4 or so presses it works it just seems that the cycle is very weird.

Comment: Before you press it, the class is ```play icon```, once you press it, it goes to ```play icon pause``` (which oddly does display the pause icon), then once more to pause it again, it goes to just ```icon``` which results in a blank icon, and then once more it goes back to ```play icon```